# How to extract data from build.sbt in command line

Tags: scala, sbt

i would like to get data like `version`, `packageName in Docker` and such somehow. I need it for my CI to tag docker image for future use.
So is there any possibility to get such values like with maven `mvn --batch-mode -f pom.xml help:evaluate -Dexpression=project.version`.
Thanks for help in advance.

So my build.sbt contains several projects and right now i am trying to use `sbt projects`,`sbt inspect` from [sbt inspect build](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.12.1/docs/Howto/inspect.html) but no luck so far.

I managed to get key values from project but now i have problem with `packageName in Docker`. i make it with: `sbt [project_name]/[key]` but for `packageName in Docker` i got:

```
sbt projectName/packageName in Docker
[error] Not a valid command: in
[error] Expected 'info'
[error] Not a valid project ID: in
[error] Expected ':' (if selecting a configuration)
[error] Not a valid key: in
[error] in
[error]   ^
```

This is part of build.sbt:

```
lazy val `name` = project
  .in(file("name"))
  .dependsOn(`name-dep`)
  .settings(defaults)
  .settings(
    packageName in Docker := "project/name",
    version := "3.1.0-SNAPSHOT",
    dockerExposedPorts := Seq(8080),
    dockerCommands ++= Seq(
      Cmd("ENTRYPOINT",
        s"bin/${executableScriptName.value}",
        "-l", "tcp://0.0.0.0:8081",
        "-e", "${EXTERNAL_URL}",
        "-c", "${CONNECTOR_URL}")
    ),
```

For version i use:

```
sbt name/version
[info] Loading project definition from /home/jenkins/.jenkins/workspace/project
[info] Set current project to root (in build file:/home/jenkins/.jenkins/workspace/)
[info] 3.1.0-SNAPSHOT
```

but i have problems with `packageName in Docker`

### My Solution:

so i managed to get those values with:

```
# sbt -Dsbt.log.noformat=true name/packageName | sed -n 3p | cut -d " " -f 2
name
```

it dosen't display whole packageName ( without `project/` ) but as i know that this is a constant i will hardcode it in CI script.

and

```
# sbt -Dsbt.log.noformat=true name/version | sed -n 3p | cut -d " " -f 2
3.1.0-SNAPSHOT
```

if anyone has better idea please share with me.

### Tip

Be advised that sbt i using ASCII codes to colorize the output so tu use it like in my solution you have to run sbt with `-Dsbt.log.noformat=true` otherwise your CI can complain about ENV's values and you wont see this.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion would be to use [sbt-native-packager](http://www.scala-sbt.org/sbt-native-packager/formats/docker.html).

Also this packager got [Docker Plugin](http://www.scala-sbt.org/sbt-native-packager/formats/docker.html)

Which gives you out of box docker image on sbt build with version number. We are using sbt-package-manager in all our modules.

Comment: we are using the same packager, but how i can get values of `packageName in Docker` and `version in Docker` via command line ?